# Can you explain the time difference of this java program for normal code and function call

Tags: java, function, time, call

After executing code then interchange the code (first call the display function and then normal code), then see the time difference again.

I do not know why this happens.

Code:

```
import java.util.Date;
    public class Test_time {

        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            long start_time;
            long end_time;
            long diff;
   //first try      
            start_time =System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(start_time);
            String g = "g";
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            {
                    g=g+"g";
                }
            end_time = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(end_time);

            diff =  end_time - start_time ;
            System.out.println(diff);

            start_time =System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(start_time);
            display();
            end_time = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(end_time);

            diff =  end_time - start_time ;
            System.out.println(diff);
```

/* second try .. try this by commenting first try

```
    start_time =System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(start_time);
    display();
    end_time = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(end_time);

    diff =  end_time - start_time ;
    System.out.println(diff);

    start_time =System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(start_time);
    String g = "g";
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {

        g=g+"g";

    }
    end_time = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(end_time);

    diff =  end_time - start_time ;
    System.out.println(diff);
```

*/
        }

```
        static void display()
        {
            String g = "g";
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            {

                g=g+"g";

            }

        }

    }
```

Please someone explain me this behavior.

Comment: Can you post both code samples and the output you get for both?

Comment: plz run and see the time duration for execution of above two type.

Comment: Share what difference you observed , then only we can answer not everyone keeps java with him to run program always